# Issue checking if file is in use

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file, file-io

I have a number of threads which modify a file, and I am trying to check if the file is in use before doing so - to prevent race conditions.

I am using this method:

```
protected virtual bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
{
    FileStream stream = null;

    try
    {
        stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        //the file is unavailable because it is:
        //still being written to
        //or being processed by another thread
        //or does not exist (has already been processed)
        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.Close();
    }

    //file is not locked
    return false;
}
```

And calling it like so:

```
while (flag)
{
    if (IsFileLocked(new FileInfo(logPath)))
    {
       File.AppendAllText(logPath, Environment.NewLine + "Test");
       flag = false;
    }
}
```

The problem is that one process manages to write to the file, but if another attempts to write at the same time, it is not written

Comment: "check if the file is in use before doing so - to prevent race conditions" How does this work? The file could become locked between your check and the actual operation. The better solution here is for the actual operation to just handle errors properly, right?

Comment: The problem is that I would like both processes to access the file at the same time @tenfour - so would like one to wait for the file to be available

Comment: Synchronize your processes then using a mutex or semaphore, don't poll the file as a synchronization object.

Comment: you should change design and create a thread-safe class that handles access to this file. Every class which needs to access to it should use that class.

Comment: Would adding a `lock` block solve it @tenfour?

Comment: `lock` will only synchronize within the process; it won't synchronize across processes. You need to use a real `Mutex` object for this to work across processes.

Comment: You are writing the file if it is locked. Seems like you should write to the file if is is not locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the code that does the actual writing into a separate method and synchronize that, for example like this:

```
private object WRITELOCK = new object();

private void AppendToFile(string fileName, string textToAppend)
{
    lock (WRITELOCK)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(fileName, textToAppend);
    }
}
```

Then all threads would call `AppendToFile`. Please note that you still have to catch exceptions in your threads and maybe retry, but that way the file can only be written by one thread at a time.

Thread code should look like this:

```
try
{
    AppendToFile(fileName, "Hello");
}
catch (...)
{
    // Handle errors writing to file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using File locking is not easy, File Stream allows you to lock byte range of file, which is over programming to append text for logging purpose.

Synchronizing writes in the same Process.

```
private static object lockObject = new object();
public static void AppendToFile(string fileName, string text){
   lock(lockObject){
      File.AppendAllText(fileName, text);
   }
}
```

To synchronize writes in multiple process you have to use Mutex to avoid race condition.

```
public static void AppendToFile(string fileName, string text){

    var gl = new GlobalNamedLock(fileName);
    if(!gl.Lock()){
         // should not happen
         // but still throw the exception some how to notice
         throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not acquire lock");
    }

    try{
        File.AppendAllText(fileName, text);
    }finally{
        gl.Unlock();
    }

}


public class GlobalNamedLock
{
    private Mutex mtx;

    public GlobalNamedLock(string strLockName)
    {
        //Name must be provided!
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strLockName))
        {
            //Use default name
            strLockName = ((GuidAttribute)Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), false).GetValue(0)).Value.ToString();
        }

        //Create security permissions for everyone
        //It is needed in case the mutex is used by a process with
        //different set of privileges than the one that created it
        //Setting it will avoid access_denied errors.
        MutexSecurity mSec = new MutexSecurity();
        mSec.AddAccessRule(new MutexAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null),
            MutexRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

        //Create the global mutex
        bool bCreatedNew;
        mtx = new Mutex(false, @"Global\" + strLockName, out bCreatedNew, mSec);
    }

    public bool Lock()
    {
        return mtx.WaitOne();
    }

    public void Unlock()
    {
        //Release it
        mtx.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why create a separate lock object (gl.mtx) when files already have their own locking semantics? This solution is more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @ShellShock, FileStream locks are more complicated, you can only lock region of bytes, how do you calculate that?

Comment: @ShellShock, please post your answer with File Stream lock or inbuilt file lock with "AppendText" logic.

Comment: @ShellShock FileStream locks are not the answer ... it does nothing to  actually synchronize the processes. You can't wait on a filestream lock.

Answer (score 0):

You still have a race condition:

```
while (flag)
{
    if (IsFileLocked(new FileInfo(logPath)))
    {
       // Because IsFileLocked has closed the file, 
       // another thread can open the file here before 
       // File.AppendAllText opens the file.
       File.AppendAllText(logPath, Environment.NewLine + "Test");
       flag = false;
    }
}
```

The correct way to do this is to open the file and then write to it with the same stream, catching any exceptions if the file open fails and retrying. In your case, the simplest thing is to get rid of your IsFileLocked method, and put the File.AppendAllText in a try...catch. If the File.AppendAllText fails because the file is already locked, pause a little bit and then try the File.AppendAllText again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Could you kindly provide an example which is acceptable? As I have read in many places that pausing is not a good approach in general. However I might have not completely understood your suggestion

Comment: Polling on file access like this is really not a good solution. Use a mutex.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you would need to use either a monitor or a mutex in order to make sure that your check is actually doing you any good. The Monitor version is much faster but isn't process safe (in other words it will not protect you if the user opens two copies of your program). That looks like the following:

```
try
{
   Monitor.Enter(shared_variable);
   if (IsFileLocked(myFile)) return;
   // ... process file here ...
}
finally
{
   Monitor.Exit(shared_variable);
}
```

In this example, just declare the "shared_variable" as any object that can be shared across all of the threads. You can even create an object just for this purpose. The alternative with the mutex looks almost the same but it is much slower:

```
Mutex globalWait = new Mutex();
if (globalWait.WaitOne())
{
   try
   {
      if (IsFileLocked(myFile)) return;
      // ... process file here ...
   }
   finally
   {
      globalWait.ReleaseMutex();
   }
}
```

One REALLY important note, though - these "WaitOne" and "Enter" routines are going to wait indefinitely for the thread to become available. If these threads are dependent on each other in any way you might end up with a deadlock. There are lots of excellent resources out there for handling deadlocks, but its something to be very aware of!

Answer (score 0):

In general, `CanWrite`-style functions like this are *rarely, rarely* needed. Imagine this code:

```
if(CanRead(someFile))
{
    x = Read(someFile);
}
else
{
    // cannot read
}
```

There are problems with this. Readability can change between these 2 calls (so your synchronization issue still exists). You will also effectively open the file twice, when you only need to do it once. The better solution here is to just handle errors properly from Read().

```
try
{
    x = Read(someFile);
}
catch(...)
{
    // cannot read.
}
```

So more specifically, it seems you're writing a logging class that works across processes. As in my above example, no matter what, you should handle write errors in your logging class properly, without bothering with a `CanWrite` function.

The OS already will "synchronize" the file so you won't have any race conditions while writing. But of course writes might not be atomic so you could end up with some text being inserted in the middle of another processes' text.

What you want is for your logging class to form a queue with mutual exclusion. Process A takes the mutex, does everything it needs to do with the file, and passes the mutex on to process B, which takes its turn, etc.

For this you can create a named mutex, as @Akash Kava has already shown.